# How to deal with dynamic lists of data in a layout

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, coding-style

I want to display contact information in a custom layout.  My app lets the user select a contact, then I retrieve key pieces of info on that contact (phone #'s, email addy's, etc).  I want to display them to the user so they look grouped logically.  Sort of like a series of tables, so phone numbers, then email addys, then organization, etc.

I have a table format that I've been using in a different part of the app where I know the exact number of rows I'm adding and I have defined styles for the rows already.  I want to reuse those styles for this data, but android sdk won't allow for you to set the style attribute programmatically.

I could create the tables in code and set all the attributes the same as in my defined styles, but it seems like a lot of extra coding.  Any ideas on how I should approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

To reuse styles [externalize them](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to  resource end then you can apply them in multiple places.

Comment: So I did end up using TableLayout.  I already had defined all my styles externally for a related activity and I wanted this activity to have the same look.  So I want to reuse the styles I already defined.  The problem is, this new TableLayout is dynamic and has to be generated in Java code as opposed to XML.  This in and of itselft isn't a huge problem, but the fact that you can't set the style attribute for a View in java code is a bit frustrating.

Comment: One thing I did do to make it a bit easier was since I know ahead of time exactly the number of data sets (each set in a seperate tablelayout), I create all the tablelayouts in XML and set their visibility to GONE.  That way I can at least style the TableLayouts. Then in code as I'm data filling them with a variable number of rows, I set the visibility to VISIBLE for each tablelayout that I end up using.  I still can't use my TableRow styles, but it helps greatly in the overall RelativeLayout for laying out the order and placement of the tablelayouts.